# Встроить sql запрос-фильтр yii2

Tags: yii2

Только начинаю осваивать yii2. У меня есть таблица, данные которой, выводятся в gridview. Там колонка, в которую напихали дату и время. Мне время не нужно, поэтому хочу вставить такой запрос `SELECT DATE(`order_createdAt`) AS order_date FROM`order``чтобы откидывать время и выводить только дату. Куда нужно вставить это запрос?

```
'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'order_number',
        [
            'attribute' => 'order_createdAt',
            'label' => 'Дата',
'content' => function ($searchModel) {
                    return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($searchModel->order_createdAt, 'php:d-m-Y');
                }
            ],
```

Comment: опишите более подробно: покажите код, где и как у вас выводится дата на данный момент, и дайте понять что хотите получить, а то "напихать" можно по разному, но вот лишние запросы к бд вам точно не нужны

Comment: @Blacknife есть таблица, для которой я создал модель. в таблице есть поле order_date, содержащее информацию типа `2016-12-11 22:29:02`(в этом виде в данный момент и выводится). Мне нужно только `2016-12-11 `.

Comment: @Blacknife перестал работать поиск по такому формату даты

Comment: добавь в вопрос код и перепутал наверное в ответе надо не `order_date` а `order_createdAt`

Comment: @Blacknife сам код все корректно выводит. Вот два варианта вывода. Первый это твой вариант, второй без фильтров(как в базе). Если ввести в строку поиска `12-12-2016` - ничего не находит. И еще непонятно почему вывел записи как за 12 декабря?

Comment: @Blacknife вот как выглядит http://joxi.ru/823KeVztB3WW2O

Comment: всё правильно, в базе же сначала год идёт `2016-12-11 00:00:00`, просто выводи как тебе надо, я ведь лишь пример показал: `'php:Y-m-d'`, а в модели search нужно что-то типа `... WHERE `order_createdAt` LIKE '2016-11-16%'` либо `...  WHERE date(order_createdAt) = '2016-11-16'`, тут по разному можно, но я на своих проектах использую в основном UnixTimeStamp

Comment: а вообще в фильтр удобней будет datepicker поставить, чтобы не писать дату вручную

Comment: @Blacknife почему поле без фильтра `2016-12-11 22:29:02`  - 11 декабря, а с фильтром 12? поменял вывод на `Y-m-d`. Хочу поставить какой-нибудь daterangepicker, на эту колонку

Comment: потому-что 'php:Y-m-d' берёт timezone сервера может быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких дополнительных запросов строить не нужно, а дату можно перед выводом отформатировать разными способами:

Первый способ будет форматировать дату исходя из настроек [yii-i18n-formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$dateFormat-detail), вы можете настроить его желаемым образом в своей конфигурации:

```
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
        'locale' => 'ru-RU',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
        'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        'datetimeFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'
    ],
    ...
]


'columns' => [
    'order_date:date',
    'created_at:datetime',
    'updated_at:time',
    ...
]
```

второй и третий способ позволяют выводить желаемый вид даты, игнорируя глобальные настройки [форматтера](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$dateFormat-detail):

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'order_date',
        'label' => 'Дата',
        'format' => ['date', 'php:d-m-Y']
    ],
    ...
]
```

либо

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'order_date',
        'label' => 'Дата',
        'content' => function ($model) {
            return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->order_date, 'php:d-m-Y');
        }
    ],
    ...
]
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html